# Is the sharepoint check in check out feature meant to be used only for microsoft office files-i.e. word, excel and powerpoint files?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, check-out

I am trying to create a library of files which are used for PLCs ( Programmable Logic Controllers). The file name ends in .acd for these file. Right now when i Check out a file, it is not downloaded in the sharepoint drafts folder in My Documents. However the green arrow mark on the icon appears.

Currently I am working around it by checking out the file, then downloading a copy of the file, editing what i want, then discarding the checkout in the library and then uploading a newer version of the file.

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2010 and the site administrator has disabled editing with sharepoint designer, but i can request that to be enabled if required.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no such restriction like that. Non-MS Office files can also be uploaded in SharePoint Document Libraries. However by default SharePoint Server 2010 blocks certain file type extensions that can't be uploaded in document libraries. But .acd is not one of them. You can get the full list here:

SharePoint Server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx

SharePoint Foundation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287701.aspx

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Office applications integrate with SharePoint and bring the check in options into the client for the user. Third-party applications need to implement the resources to make the user experience with SharePoint cleaner